# Link metadata not showing appropriately

Tags: node.js, express, dns, meta-tags

We have 2 domains.

One is hosted and provided directly by Heroku: https://dynamic-universal-link-567a0b6a1e8c.herokuapp.com/zooparkFuture/2y035mmkxysj5ueb

One is in another hosting called super hosting: https://app-earnings-link.com/zooparkFuture/2y035mmkxysj5ueb

When the first link - which is hosted in Heroku - is shared somewhere, the meta data is visible; there is an image, a title, and a description.

When the second link - which is hosted in super hosting - is shared somewhere, the meta data isn’t visible although the HTML and headers of the links are completely identical.

Here is the code for both links:

```js
const result = response.data.result
        console.log(result)
        if (result) {
          res.setHeader(‘Content-Type’, ‘text/html’);
          res.send(`
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
              <meta property=“og:title” content=“Welcome to ${result.title}“>
              <meta property=“og:description” content=“${result.description}“>
              <meta property=“og:image” content=“${result.image}“>
              <meta property=“og:url” content=“${result.url}>
              <meta property=“og:type” content=“website”>
              <title>${result.title}</title>
              <script>setTimeout(() => {
                window.location.href = ‘${result.url}’
              },10)</script>
            </head>
            <body>
              <h1>Welcome to Your Website</h1>
              <!-- Rest of your HTML content -->
            </body>
            </html>
          `);
        } else {
          const result = {}
          res.setHeader(‘Content-Type’, ‘text/html’);
          res.send(`
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
              <meta property=“og:title” content=“Welcome to ${result.title}“>
              <meta property=“og:description” content=“${result.description}“>
              <meta property=“og:image” content=“${result.image}“>
              <meta property=“og:url” content=“${result.url}“>
              <meta property=“og:type” content=“website”>
              <title>${result.title}</title>
              <script>setTimeout(() => {
              },1000)</script>
            </head>
            <body>
              <h1>Welcome to Your Website</h1>
              <!-- Rest of your HTML content -->
            </body>
            </html>
          `);
        }
```

[image of meta tags in dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maURG.png)

[image of domain settings in dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaz6w.png)

[image of heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjSbF.png)

Any idea why two links with identical setup work differently and how can we achieve the same behaviour for the link which is hosted in superhosting?